# Get url for custom route in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

In my ASP.Net mvc application I have changed the default route registration in startup.cs to

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    template: "{customer}/{language=fi-FI}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

So all routes would contain the customer id and the current language. Custom segment matching takes care of putting the customer and language info in new urls so when the requested url is /customer1/fi-fi/somecontroller/someaction any generated url like this

```
<a asp-controller="othercontroller" asp-action="otheraction">Some action</a>
```

would be generated correctly with the customer and language code in it.

The question is, how should I generate the url so I can specify the customer and language code without having to do string concatenation? I would need this e.g. in the links for changing language.

I have tried

```
<a asp-controller="somecontroller" asp-action="someaction" asp-route="default" asp-route-customer="customer2" asp-route-language="en-us">Some action in other language and other customer</a>
```

but that says that I cannot specify action and controller when asp-route is defined and if I remote asp-route then nothing changes.

Comment: I have something similar in this project which supports folder tenants, https://github.com/joeaudette/cloudscribe I think you need to implement a route constraint for {customer} as I have done for SiteFolder. See the startup in the example web app project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by using @Url.RouteUrl, e.g.

```
@Url.RouteUrl("default", new { customer = "someothercustomer", language = "someotherlanguage", controller = "somecontroller", action = "someaction" })
```